# How do you prevent the padding surrounding an image from being clickable?

Tags: html, css, href, padding

I have a series of images that all have padding and are linkable to different sites. My problem is that I don't want the padding itself to be clickable, just the image.

Here's the padding for the images:

```
.slideshow img {
    padding: 15px 15px 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

And here's an example of what the slideshow looks like:

```
<div class="slideshow"> 
<a target="window" href="http://google.com"><img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Here's some alt text." width="960" height="300" /></a>
<a target="window" href="http://www.google.com"><img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="Here is some more alt text." width="960" height="300" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `<a>` elements with some placeholder element (`<span>` for example) and set the padding on that.

```css
.slideshow span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px 15px 45px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <span><a target="window" href="http://google.com"><img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Here's some alt text." width="960" height="300" /></a></span>
  <span><a target="window" href="http://www.google.com"><img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="Here is some more alt text." width="960" height="300" /></a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that not only the image is clickable, but especially the a link around it. So adding a normal margin to the image wouldn't work either, since it would just stretch the link.

An easy way out would be to add an extra element around the links and add the styling to that {upd: like Amit just posted}. But here is an alternative that doesn't require you to change the HTML. It basically adds a margin to the links themselves, and fills that margin with a shadow with the same color as the background color.

```css
.slideshow a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 15px 15px 45px;
  box-shadow: -0px -0px 0px 15px #eee; 
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <a target="window" href="http://google.com">
    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Here's some alt text." width="960" height="300" />
  </a>
  <a target="window" href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="Here is some more alt text." width="960" height="300" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that padding is interpreted as a part of the content.
If possible, I would recommend you to use 'margin' instead of padding.
The result are nearly (or even) the same, and you will not get that blank clickable.

Basically, change you .slideshow to match this:

```
.slideshow img {
    margin: 15px 15px 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Hope this helps